# how to delete the gateway address in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, ping

How to delete the gateway by using the command line in ubuntu 9.10? Since I have tested these gateway address, I need a commmand line to delete gateway address.

Answer (score 2):

`ip route del default`

Note that if you have to ask that, you probably won't be able to do much with it.